# Ajax upload não envia imagem e nem parametro

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou tentando fazer um upload sem From, para upload de imagem, mas não consigo.

**html**

```
<input id="avatar" type="file" name="avatar" />
<button id="btnOcorrenciaSalvar">Salvar</button>
```

**Código javascript:**

```
$("#btnOcorrenciaSalvar").click(function() {


                event.preventDefault();
                var form_data = new FormData();
                nomeFoto = event.filename;

                var file_data = $("#avatar").prop("files")[0];

                form_data.append("file", file_data)
                form_data.append("foto", nomeFoto)


                $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://url.com.br/temp.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: form_data,
                  async: false,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  success: function (returndata) {
                      //$("#productFormOutput").html(returndata);
                      alert(form_data);
                  },
                  error: function () {
                      alert("error in ajax form submission");
                  }
                });

                return false;


            });
```

**Código PHP para receber o POST:**

```
<?php 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], "ocorrencias/" . $_POST["foto"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você utilizasse um form seria bem mais simples:

```
<form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
  <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem" />

</form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* #imagem é o id do input, ao alterar o conteudo do input execurará a função baixo */
    $('#imagem').live('change', function () {
        $('#visualizar').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Enviando..."/> Enviando...'); /* Efetua o Upload sem dar refresh na pagina */
        $('#formulario').ajaxForm({target: '#visualizar' /* o callback será no elemento com o id #visualizar */}).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Bom dia. Esta aparecendo esse erro ``Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ``. na linha onde tem o ``$('#formulario').ajaxForm``. O que é isso?

Comment: no lugar do #formulario deve ficar o id do seu formulário!

Answer (score 0):

O erro `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, é porque foi utilizado o plugin `ajaxForm`, e você não importou ele.

Se quiser continuar usando jQuery sem plugins, coloque um:

`var_dump($_FILES);`

Para entender o que está realmente sendo enviado pelo teu javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que é porque você esqueceu de declarar o parâmetro event da função click(), ex:

$("#btnOcorrenciaSalvar").click(function(**event**) {

e você chamou sem ele existir: *event.preventDefault();*